# In android market is there a subscription facility?

Tags: android, google-play, subscription, in-app-billing

Currently I Am developing an magazine reader app. In my app I want to provide the Subscription facility where user can have monthly subscriptions. I am having a doubt that is there a subscription facility in android market. I went through the Google docs.I fond that now its not available. But still I am having a doubt and little bit confused. Can any one tell me about this. Any help will be appreciated.I really want to clarify this for the further movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is an API that facilitates subscription. It's called [In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html) and it's one of the most difficult to use payment APIs I ever encountered.

Answer (score 0):

The subscription based payment model was recently announced, and as Bill The Ape has said, it is quite difficult to use and understand.

Some useful links:

- [In-app billing overview](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_overview.html)
- [Implementing in-app billing with a tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html)
- [Implementing subscriptions](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_subscriptions.html#token)

You can play around with the sample application, and re-use bits for your own app. If you do, make sure you read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_best_practices.html) so that the app is secure.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is:

https://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html

I actually disagree with Bill The Ape. The documentation and sample code is pretty decent. Google has a sample application that demonstrates subscriptions. The only issue is testing subscriptions, that's where there's very little support